# Unable to click a radio button inside an iframe when testing on Selenium

Tags: selenium, iframe

I am trying to access a radio button inside an iframe when running tests on a web application on Selenium.

The button inside the forms looks like

```
<input type="radio" value="facebook" onclick="onClick()"> Facebook
```

And I try to access it using

```
this.browser.element(by.xpath('//input[@value = \'facebook\']'))
```

But that doesnt seem to find the element. Any feedback appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you switch to the iframe in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you have iframe you need to switch over the element.
There are 3 ways to switch to the frame:

- By Index
- By Name or Id
- By WebElement

Here is how to switch:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(index/name/webelement);
```

You can identify the number of the iframes in the page by:

```
Int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
```